# How to track a product with built-in barcode/qrcode that have different purchase details. Multiple time purchase us unique built-in barcode/qrcode

Tags: asp.net-core, database-design, barcode, point-of-sale, inventory-management

I would like to help me.

I have a scenario like
a product with built-in barcode/qrcode to be purchased and sold but each product have same built-in barcode/qrcode. But each product is purchased multiple time with different details.

While making sale how to identify this product scanned have picked the same product with details of multiple purchase with different purchase price and sell price.

currently we generated & created  unique batcheid
This batcheid generated QR code with all details of purchasedetails_tbl in batchtable_tbl working correctly because each purchase has it.
.
.
.
We want to use the built-in product barcode/qrcode.
And track the product purchase and sold details.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you purchase a product with an existing barcode.  The barcode is the same on all copies of the same product.  You purchase lots of these products at different times and at different prices.  You want to track individual products so you can match your purchase price to the sale price.  Do I have your question correct?

Comment: If the barcode is the same for all of them, then you can't use it alone to track the individual items. You'd need an additional barcode/label etc. printed on them that identifies it in your system.

Comment: `each product is purchased multiple time with different details`, Is this different detail enough to differentiate your multiple products? If not, then you can't track each of your products just with the built-in barcode because you can't tell them apart. You need to add unique identifiers to them in order to track individual products, e.g. when each product was sold.

Comment: Please refer to this article for ideas. [GS1 Application Identifiers](https://www.gs1.org/standards/barcodes/application-identifiers)

Comment: @gilbertLeBlanc yes you got me right

Comment: @juunas currently we doing the same printing barcode as batch purchas and have unique I'd that identify the details of product on that batchid as purchsed. The client want to prevent barcode printing expense and use built-in barcods

Comment: @chen that's probably issue I am trying to solve.If I add new purchase witg same product barcode so may have lost pervious purchas details of product like product sell price , purchas price expired date and also update the stock quantity.

Comment: Do you want to track a certain type of product or each of a type of products? If it is the latter, you must have a unique identifier that can be distinguished, otherwise you will not be able to distinguish them.